# without iterating an array, How to check a value exisitng inside the loop or not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

```
i have an array.
key_values = 
    ["loc=june 1  2 jubli's, Captain tim, BI",
     "locSlug=june-1-",
     "-2-jubli's_Captain-tim_BI",
     "lat=29.404153823852539",
     "long=-54.88862609863281",
     "status=7",
     "pg=10",
     "pgsz=15",
     "sprefix=/kings_search",
     "city=Captain tim",
     "neighborhood=june 1 ",
     " 2 jubli's",
     "state_id=BI",
     "county_fips=15045"]
```

This is my array. I am iterating this till the end , when the current value includes "locSlug" or  "neighborhood" then i am checking for next value whether it has "=" or not . if it has "=" then i am not doing anything, otherwise i am adding next value and my current value with "&". But i dont want to iterate this for whole values. How can i do it without iterating the whole loop.I have written code like as shown below.

```
def check_for_special_character(key_values)
    key_values.each_with_index do |val,index|
      unless index+1 >= key_values.length       
        if (val.include?("locSlug=") || val.include?("neighborhood=")) && !key_values[index+1].include?("=") 
          key_values[index] = [val, key_values[index+1]].join("&") 
          key_values.delete_at(index+1)
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

The above code is working fine but i dont want to do in this way.  need your suggestions.
If u need any further clarifications please ask.

Comment: How are you getting this array in the first place? Is it from a third party api or from your another code that generates it?

Comment: I am getting a string from cookie. I am splitting that string with '&'. so i am getting this array.

Comment: Now that we know the source, did you try accessing these cookies with `cookies[:locSlug]` and `cookies[:neighborhood]` instead?

Comment: Tne business about the equals sign is not clear, but it might be if you edited to show the desired output.

Comment: @Harshavardhanreddy _"I am getting a string from cookie"_ – how does the raw string look like?

Comment: Suppose  cookie = "loc=june 1  2 jubli's, Captain tim, BI&locSlug=june-1-&-2-jubli's_Captain-tim_BI&lat=29.404153823852539&long=-54.88862609863281&status=7&pg=10&pgsz=15&sprefix=/kings_search&city=Captain tim&neighborhood=june 1 & 2 jubli's&state_id=BI&county_fips=15045"  . I am splitting this cookie with "&". When i do like this some values which are having '&' value they are getting broken. so i am performing this above operation.

Comment: I have deleted my answer because the original request was not to help, but just to write the code for free. Also, the question is downvoted.

Comment: I have already solved this one. But the thing is i want ur suggestion that how can i write the code without iterating the total array. Sorry :-) sir.

Answer (score 0):

### Convert Array to Hash, Then Access By Key

There may be a more efficient way of doing this if you have access to the original data object (e.g. a cookie, JSON string, or database query). However, assuming that you can't access the source data directly for some reason, or that you're just working with an array that you can't otherwise control, you can convert your data into a Ruby [Hash object](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html) and then access the values you want by key. For example:

```
# Split your array elements on "=", and then convert the resulting array of
# arrays to a hash so you can return values by key. You need to have some
# sort of guard in place for sub-arrays that don't have exactly two elements.

hash = key_values.map { |e| e.split ?= }.select { |a| a.size.eql? 2 }.to_h

hash.fetch 'locSlug'
#=> "june-1-"

hash.fetch 'neighborhood'
#=> "june 1 "
```

Comment: `?=` is lovely.

Comment: locSlug value got broken. it shoyld be in the format of "june-1-&-2-jubli's_Captain-tim_BI"

Answer (score 0):

The string you are retrieving from the cookie looks like this:

```
str = "loc=june 1  2 jubli's, Captain tim, BI&locSlug=june-1-&-2-jubli's_Capta"\
      "in-tim_BI&lat=29.404153823852539&long=-54.88862609863281&status=7&pg=10"\
      "&pgsz=15&sprefix=/kings_search&city=Captain tim&neighborhood=june 1 & 2"\
      " jubli's&state_id=BI&county_fips=15045"
```

As you can see, `&` is used as both, a delimiter and a regular character:

```
"loc=june 1  2 jubli's, Captain tim, BI&locSlug=june-1-&-2-jubli's_Captain-..."
#                                      ^               ^
#                                  delimiter       character
```

In other words: your string is broken. You should fix this by writing a *properly escaped* string to the cookie in the first place. For a [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), you'd use [percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). It should look like this:

```
str = "loc=june+1++2+jubli%27s%2C+Captain+tim%2C+BI&locSlug=june-1-%26-2-jubli"\
      "%27s_Captain-tim_BI&lat=29.404153823852539&long=-54.88862609863281&stat"\
      "us=7&pg=10&pgsz=15&sprefix=%2Fkings_search&city=Captain+tim&neighborhoo"\
      "d=june+1+%26+2+jubli%27s&state_id=BI&county_fips=15045"
```

This can be parsed via:

```
Rack::Utils.parse_query(str)
#=> {
#     "loc"=>"june 1  2 jubli's, Captain tim, BI",
#     "locSlug"=>"june-1-&-2-jubli's_Captain-tim_BI",
#     "lat"=>"29.404153823852539",
#     "long"=>"-54.88862609863281",
#     "status"=>"7",
#     "pg"=>"10",
#     "pgsz"=>"15",
#     "sprefix"=>"/kings_search",
#     "city"=>"Captain tim",
#     "neighborhood"=>"june 1 & 2 jubli's",
#     "state_id"=>"BI",
#     "county_fips"=>"15045"
#   }
```

Comment: Hi sir, I am setting the cookie values in somany places. I am unable to write a properly escaped string to the cookie. and the values i am getting from API.

Comment: @Harshavardhanreddy it's time to refactor your code and get it right I guess ;-)

Comment: yes sir. you are right. I am trying to increase the performance